# How to sort a list of lists in python

Tags: python

Consider a list of lists! I want to sort the outer list according to the length of the inner list. Can someone tell me a nice way of doing this?

Here is the concrete example:

```
graph = {'node_1': ['node_2', 'node_4'], 'node_2': ['node_1', 'node_3', 'node_5'], 'node_3': ['node_2', 'node_6'], 
         'node_4': ['node_1', 'node_5'], 'node_5': ['node_4', 'node_2', 'node_6'], 'node_6': ['node_5', 'node_3']}

nodes = ["node_1", "node_2", "node_3", "node_4", "node_5", "node_6"]
connections = [(s,d) for s in nodes for d in nodes if s!=d]

def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start] #do not append the list, but create a new one!
    if start == end:
        return [path]
    if start not in graph.keys():
        return []
    paths = []
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
            for newpath in newpaths:
                    paths.append(newpath)
    return paths

example = find_all_paths(graph, 'node_1', 'node_6')
print(example)
```

This example returns a list that contains all the possible paths to go from source node 1 to destination node 6 in a network. However, I only want to print the 2 shortest possible paths. The function `find_all_paths` returns a list of lists. I want to sort this list and then only print the first 2 entries of it, which should be the 2 shortest paths.

Comment: If two lists have the same length, how do you decide what order they belong in (or is it arbitrary)?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the list of lists with `len` as the key function:

```
example = sorted(find_all_paths(graph, 'node_1', 'node_6'), key=len)[:2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `key` keyword argument of `sorted()`:

```
sorted_list = sorted(original_list, key=lambda x: len(x))
```

Or more simply:

```
sorted_list = sorted(original_list, key=len)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sorted` to sort list of lists. It takes an optional `key` parameter where we can specify on what basis we need to sort:

```
lst = [['node_1', 'node_2', 'node_3', 'node_6'],
       ['node_1', 'node_2', 'node_5', 'node_6'],
       ['node_1', 'node_4', 'node_5', 'node_2', 'node_3', 'node_6'],
       ['node_1', 'node_4', 'node_5', 'node_6']]

print(sorted(lst, key=len)[:2])

# [['node_1', 'node_2', 'node_3', 'node_6'], 
#  ['node_1', 'node_2', 'node_5', 'node_6']]
```